# UIDatePicker in countdown mode: Can I have a countdown thats longer than 23:59?

Tags: ios, xib

I want the user to be able to elegantly enter an NSTimeInterval, and UIDatePicker's `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer` picker mode seems perfect for that.

However, in countdown mode the date picker only allows a maximum value of 23 hours and 59 minutes – it's not possible to enter anything longer than that by default.

Is there a way I can make the date picker's interval greater than 24 hours? If not, what other ways are there – maybe a custom UIPickerView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess I have to create my own subclass of UIPicker then.